# Dictionary is getting overriden while adding another entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function to create dictionary

```
def Bowler_creator (Name): 

    """
    This function will create the dictionaries for the batting player

    """
    global bowler;
    bowler =    { 
            Name : { "number_of_overs":0.0,
                    "number_of_runs":0,
                    "number_of_wickets":0,
                    'economy_rate':0.0,
                    'Maiden overs':0
                    },

                }
Current_Bowler = input("Enter the bowler's name\n");

Bowler_creator(Current_Bowler);
Bowler_creator('jafda');
```

My idea is that i will be calling this function like below so that new key with the same entry values will be created for this dictionary

So as per my idea, the dictionary should have created two elements with two keys `Current_Bowler` and `jafda`, but after I try to print the dictionary it´s returning the latest one only. Could you please let me know why my dictionary is getting overridden with a newer key?

Comment: You are creating a new dictionary each time... did you mean `bowler[Name] = { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You are *replacing* the dictionary with an entirely new dictionary each time.

You should create the dictionary *once*, then add keys:

```
bowler = {}

def Bowler_creator (Name): 
    bowler[Name] = {
        "number_of_overs":0.0,
        "number_of_runs":0,
        "number_of_wickets":0,
        'economy_rate':0.0,
        'Maiden overs':0
    }
```

Note: because the function no longer needs to assign a new object to `bowler`, you don't need to mark it as a global either. Assigning directly to the key modifies the global dictionary directly.

Comment: So as the dictionary wont tell us that it is getting replaced, In order to have a new entry we must start like bowler[Name]={}, got it

Comment: @SaiKoti: you re-bound `bowler` by assigning something else to it; `bowler = ...`. That expression happened to assign a completely new dictionary. By assigning to a key instead, you only replace the value for that key, not the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new dictionary every time in the function `Bowler_creator`.
Try doing

```
bowler[Name] = { "number_of_overs":0.0,
                    "number_of_runs":0,
                    "number_of_wickets":0,
                    'economy_rate':0.0,
                    'Maiden overs':0
               }
```

Comment: Hi Afaq, Your answer itself included the value of the key inside the dictionary, No problem thats also helpful